# ¿Cómo capturar la respuesta de un request error si estoy usando AJAX en Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, ajax, formrequest

de antemano gracias por cualquier colaboración o aporte a este problema, soy un poco nuevo en laravel, actualmente estoy haciendo un CRUD con ajax y todo va bien por ahora, el único inconveniente es cuando hay un error en el Form Request ya que este da como resultado un JSON directo al ajax.

Este es el JSON:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que muestra el ajax por consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera capturar el mensaje del error dentro del controlador para luego incorporarle un componente de vista que ya tengo creado y este se retorne al ajax.

cuando se hace click en el boton de editar llama a este ajax:

```
        $(".Editar").click(function (event) {
      let Username = $(
        document.getElementsByName("Username" + this.id)
      ).val();
      let Name = $(document.getElementsByName("Name" + this.id)).val();
      let Email = $(document.getElementsByName("Email" + this.id)).val();
      let Tipo = $(document.getElementsByName("Tipo" + this.id)).val();

      if (
        confirm("Seguro que quiere editar los datos del id: " + this.id)
      ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "/listarUser",
          type: "patch",
          data: {
            _token: token,
            id: this.id,
            username: Username,
            name: Name,
            email: Email,
            tipo: Tipo,
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $("#ContenTitulo").html(data);
            buscarUsers();
          },
          error: function (data) {
            console.log("error");

            console.log(data.responseJSON);

            buscarUsers();
          },
        });
      }
    });
```

el cual envía los datos al controlador a la funcion update:

```
public function update(EditarUserRequest $request){

**Aquí debo capturar la respuesta del request para ver si realizo lo demás**

$user = User::find($request->id);
$user->username = $request->username;
$user->name = $request->name;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->tipo = $request->tipo;
$user->save();


return view('/components.mensaje', ['titulo'=> 'Modulo de Usuarios del Sistema']); 
}
```

y este es el archivo del request:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        //
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
        'name' => 'required',
        'tipo' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Si la respuesta es un error de validación, no vas a poder capturarlo en el controlador, ya que la ejecución no va a llegar hasta ahí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas tardes he encontrado dos soluciones a lo que quería hacer el primero se salta el archivo de form request y hace la validación directo en el controller.

tenemos que incluir esta linea al principio del archivo:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

luego en la función del controlador seria de la siguiente manera:

```
public function update(Request $request){
 $validatedData = $request->validated();
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
  'name' => 'required',
  'tipo' => 'required',
  'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',

 ]);
 if ($validator->fails()) {
  return view('/components.mensaje', ['titulo'=> 'Modulo de Usuarios del Sistema'])->withErrors($validator);
 }

}
```

esto me retornaría al ajax y luego lo mostraría a donde quiere

Answer (score 0):

la segunda solución que encontré usa la respuesta de error del form request esta la capturamos con el ajax en la sección de **error** y los datos los envió a otra función global que cree para manejar todos los errores de form request.

primero en el archivo que se usara la funcion de error hay que agregar esta linea:

```
import { errors } from "../global";
```

luego creas tu ajax con la respuesta success y error:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "/listarUser",
          type: "patch",
          data: {
            _token: token,
            id: this.id,
            username: Username,
            name: Name,
            email: Email,
            tipo: Tipo,
          },
          success: function (data) {
            $("#ContenTitulo").html(data);
            buscarUsers();
          },
          error: function (data) {
            console.log("respuesta por error");
            errors(token, data.responseJSON.errors);
          },
        });
```

función global que maneja los errores, esta en el archivo **global.js**, este envia los errores a un controlador que devuelve la vista:

```
const errors = function (token, error) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Errors",
    type: "post",
    data: {
      _token: token,
      errors: error,
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#ContenTitulo").html(data);
    },
  });
};
export { errors };
```

controller que maneja los errores de los form request:

```
public function Errors(Request $request){
      return view('/components.mensaje', ['titulo'=> 'Modulo de Usuarios del Sistema'])->withErrors($request->errors);
    }
```

quería hacerlo sin tener que enviar la respuesta del error a otro controlador mas, pero por ahora no he encontrado esa forma y con esta me conformo.